# solana/web3.js error import

Tags: web3.js

@solana/web3.js import error when launching cypress. And on windows everything works fine, but on MacOS an error appears

```
./node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js 1976:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1976:27)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   if (transaction.recentBlockhash != null && transaction.lastValidBlockHeight != null) {
|     status = (await connection.confirmTransaction({
>       abortSignal: options?.abortSignal,
|       signature: signature,
|       blockhash: transaction.recentBlockhash
```

Comment: I think, you have to update your node-modules to latest version. Run this command: 'yarn upgrade-interactive'

Comment: @DoublersKay Unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: The problem was solved by changing the version of @solana/web3.js from version 17.3.3 to version 17.3.0

Comment: Great, Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates a problem with this line:

```
options?.abortSignal
```

This is the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Your solution will require convincing Cypress to parse this syntax. Seek advice from others having the same trouble, [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/16914#issuecomment-1179996139).